# Insulate my window with water heater blankets?

Tags: insulation, heating, windows, energy-efficiency

I have some windows that I want to insulate at night during the winter. Would it make sense to use water heater blankets, doing something or other to secure the edges?

I'm wondering

- whether you think this would significantly affect heat loss through
  the window,
- whether it would cause any condensation problems,
- potential health risks from the fiberglass,
- and about any unintended consequences I might be missing.

Comment: Stretch poly air tight might work better if there air leaks. Thats what I used in Winterpeg.

Comment: Thanks!! What about both?

Comment: Check the answers here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/202602/97780

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use rigid styrofoam boards cut to the size you need and use a "friction fit" cut to hold them in place Those panels are easy to cut with a box cutter knife and are rated at an R5/inch. They are sold at most home stores (orange or blue) for about $20 to $25 a 4X8' sheet. This may be a better choice than a water heater blanket.

Comment: Be sure to put the insulation on the outside or you will have a large condensation problem.